# Which is better in general: fresh vegetables or frozen vegetables

Tags: nutrition, vegetable

Where I live, we have fresh vegetables in abundance at groceries. We also have frozen vegetables at the same stores.

I have read several articles (I don't have the links right now) which tell that frozen vegetables are better than fresh vegetables.I have a hard time believing that this is the case.

I have the general impression that anything fresh is always better. And if it's possible to get fresh vegetables, I always choose fresh over frozen.

Is it true that frozen vegetables are better than fresh ones? And if so, why is is considered better?

Comment: I am not going to answer as I don't have source.  Yes fresh is better.  A freezer is not going to produce vitamins.  That said a frozen vegetable is still very healthy in the overall range of food products.   It is probably only behind fresh vegetable.

Comment: Probably for the same reason that frozen seafood is often better than fresh: time. Frozen produce is often picked, cleaned and frozen all in one day, just as seafood is often cleaned and frozen right on board the fishing vessel that caught it. Fresh produce, on the other hand, will likely have been picked more than 24 hours before you buy it. Therefore, the frozen food is actually fresher than the fresh food.

Comment: You will probably get better answers to this in cooking.stackexchange.

Comment: @CareyGregory i guess that makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Frozen vegetables are just as good if not better than fresh vegetables at a grocery store, provided that the vegetables are frozen immediately after harvest.

There are many online articles that point to this, but here's an example from a recent NY Times article:

> Nutrient level differences between fresh and frozen produce are so minor they aren’t likely to impact overall health.  Vitamin content occasionally was higher in some frozen foods but researchers found no consistent differences between fresh and frozen. Frozen broccoli, for example, had more riboflavin than fresh broccoli. But frozen peas had less riboflavin than fresh peas. Frozen corn, green beans and blueberries had more vitamin C than fresh.

http://well.blogs.nytimes.com/2016/11/18/are-frozen-fruits-and-vegetables-as-nutritious-as-fresh/?emc=eta1